# Express: Handling multiple rest api calls which depends on one another

Tags: node.js, rest, express

I came across this roadblock today and wasn't sure on the right way to tackle it. Let's say I have to make four calls to different rest apis.

```
/A, /B, /C, and /D
```

If POST /A and /B succeeds, but POST /C fails, I will not execute POST /D and I would have to DELETE /A and /B to revert my changes. Basically if one of them fail they should all fail and no changes should be made to any of the services.

I was wondering if it was possible to solve this problem asynchronously or would I have to make each call sequentially?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
function task(options, done){
    // options.url will have the URL; 
    // you can add more options

    request.post(options.url).response(function(err, data){
        if(/* successful */)
            done();
        else
            request.delete(options.url);
    });
}

// do A
task({url: '/A'}, function(){
    // if this is called that means A was successful
    // do B
    task({url: '/B'}, function(){
        // .. and so on ...
    })
});
```

This is just a simple example. There are better/prettier ways like [chaining](http://google.com/search?q=node+function+chaining) or [promises](http://google.com/search?q=node+promise+q+bluebird)

---

To undo *previous* action, you could do this:

```
function task(method, url, next, fail) {
    request[method](url).response(function(err) {
        if (!next) return;
        next(function(err) {
            if (err) // undoThis // then call `fail` (to undo previous)
                request.delete(url, fail);
        });
    });
}

function doA()   { task('post',   '/A', doB); }
function undoA() { task('delete', '/A'); }
function doB()   { task('post',   '/B', doC, undoA); }
function undoB() { task('delete', '/B'); }
function doC()   { task('post',   '/C', doD, undoB); }
function undoC() { task('delete', '/C'); }
function doD()   { task('post',   '/D', null, undoC); }
```

But looking at it, I'd too go with handling it with stack.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I'm just wondering if this method will allow me to delete /A if /B fails? Otherwise would I have to use something like a stack to save urls from successful calls and start popping and calling delete on the urls if a subsequent call fail?